# jQuery Audio Stop once Link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mp3, lightbox

I have two jQuery scripts running: one for an audio mp3 player, and another to display a YouTube video in a LightBox. Right now, if someone clicks an audio file to play, it continues to play even if the link for the video is clicked.

I would like for the audio to stop playing, so that when the LightBox opens, I can autoplay the video and the user can watch that.

**Audio player implementation:**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/styles.css" />
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a class="audioButton" href="mp3/dontthinktwice.mp3">
        Don't Think Twice - Bob Dylan</a>
</body>
```

**Audio Player Script:**

```
(function($) {
var defaults = {
    audioButtonClass: "audioButton",
    autoPlay: null,
    codecs: [{
        name: "OGG",
        codec: 'audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'
    }, {
        name: "MP3",
        codec: 'audio/mpeg'
    }],
    continuous: false,
    extension: null,
    flashAudioPlayerPath: "libs/swf/player.swf",
    flashExtension: ".mp3",
    flashObjectID: "audioPlayer",
    loadingClass: "loading",
    loop: false,
    playerContainer: "player",
    playingClass: "playing",
    swfobjectPath: "libs/swfobject/swfobject.js",
    volume: 0.5
},
    currentTrack, isPlaying = false,
    isFlash = false,
    audio, $buttons, $tgt, $el, playTrack, resumeTrack, pauseTrack, methods = {
        play: function(element) {
            $tgt = element;
            currentTrack = _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href"));
            isPlaying = true;
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);

            if (isFlash) {
                if (audio) {
                    _methods.removeListeners(window);
                }
                audio = document.getElementById(defaults.flashObjectID);
                _methods.addListeners(window);
                audio.playFlash(currentTrack + defaults.extension);
            } else {
                if (audio) {
                    audio.pause();
                    _methods.removeListeners(audio);
                }
                audio = new Audio("");
                _methods.addListeners(audio);
                audio.id = "audio";
                audio.loop = defaults.loop ? "loop" : "";
                audio.volume = defaults.volume;
                audio.src = currentTrack + defaults.extension;
                audio.play();
            }
        },

        pause: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.pauseFlash();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
            }

            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = false;
        },

        resume: function() {
            if (isFlash) {
                audio.playFlash();
            } else {
                audio.play();
            }
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);
            isPlaying = true;
        },

        playing: function() {
            return isPlaying;
        }
    },

    _methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var types;

            //set defaults
            $.extend(defaults, options);
            $el = this;

            //listen for clicks on the controls
            $(".controls").bind("click", function(event) {
                _methods.updateTrackState(event);
                return false;
            });
            $buttons = $("." + defaults.audioButtonClass);

            types = defaults.codecs;
            for (var i = 0, ilen = types.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                var type = types[i];
                if (_methods.canPlay(type)) {
                    defaults.extension = [".", type.name.toLowerCase()].join("");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!defaults.extension || isFlash) {
                isFlash = true;
                defaults.extension = defaults.flashExtension;
            }

            if (isFlash) {
                $el.html("<div id='" + defaults.playerContainer + "'/>");
                $.getScript(defaults.swfobjectPath, function() {
                    swfobject.embedSWF(defaults.flashAudioPlayerPath, defaults.playerContainer, "0", "0", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", false, false, {
                        id: defaults.flashObjectID
                    }, _methods.swfLoaded);
                });
            } else {
                if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }
            }
        },

        updateTrackState: function(evt) {
            $tgt = $(evt.target);
            if (!$tgt.hasClass("audioButton")) {
                return;
            }
            if (!audio || (audio && currentTrack !== _methods.getFileNameWithoutExtension($tgt.attr("href")))) {
                methods.play($tgt);
            } else if (!isPlaying) {
                methods.resume();
            } else {
                methods.pause();
            }
        },

        addListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).bind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        removeListeners: function(elem) {
            $(elem).unbind({
                "canplay": _methods.onLoaded,
                "error": _methods.onError,
                "ended": _methods.onEnded
            });
        },

        onLoaded: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            $tgt.addClass(defaults.playingClass);

            audio.play();
        },

        onError: function() {
            $buttons.removeClass(defaults.loadingClass);
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }
        },

        onEnded: function() {
            isPlaying = false;
            $tgt.removeClass(defaults.playingClass);
            currentTrack = "";
            if (isFlash) {
                _methods.removeListeners(window);
            } else {
                _methods.removeListeners(audio);
            }

            if (defaults.continuous) {
                var $next = $tgt.next().length ? $tgt.next() : $(defaults.audioButtonClass).eq(0);
                methods.play($next);
            }

        },

        canPlay: function(type) {
            if (!document.createElement("audio").canPlayType) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return document.createElement("audio").canPlayType(type.codec).match(/maybe|probably/i) ? true : false;
            }
        },

        swfLoaded: function() {
            if (defaults.autoPlay) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    methods.play(defaults.autoPlay);
                }, 500);
            }
        },

        getFileNameWithoutExtension: function(fileName) {
            //this function take a full file name and returns an extensionless file name
            //ex. entering foo.mp3 returns foo
            //ex. entering foo returns foo (no change)
            var fileNamePieces = fileName.split('.');
            fileNamePieces.pop();
            return fileNamePieces.join(".");
        }
    };

$.fn.ubaPlayer = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
        return _methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jquery.ubaPlayer");
    }
};
```

**LightBox Implementation:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/videobox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="videobox/css/videobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /></head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sAnENc6ObI" rel="vidbox" title="The Rainbox Connection - Live at the Berklee Performance Center"><img src="playbtn.png" name="fakeplay" id="fakeplay">The Rainbow Connection (Video)</a>
</body>
```

**LightBox Script:**

```
var Videobox = {
init: function (options) {
    // init default options
    this.options = Object.extend({
        resizeDuration: 400,    // Duration of height and width resizing (ms)
        initialWidth: 250,      // Initial width of the box (px)
        initialHeight: 250,     // Initial height of the box (px)
        defaultWidth: 625,      // Default width of the box (px)
        defaultHeight: 350, // Default height of the box (px)
        animateCaption: true,   // Enable/Disable caption animation
        flvplayer: 'swf/flvplayer.swf'
    }, options || {});

    this.anchors = [];
    $A($$('a')).each(function(el){
        if(el.rel && el.href && el.rel.test('^vidbox', 'i')) {
            el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
      e = new Event(e);
      e.stop();
      this.click(el);
            }.bind(this));
            this.anchors.push(el);
        }
}, this);

    this.overlay = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbOverlay').injectInside(document.body);
    this.center = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCenter').setStyles({width: this.options.initialWidth+'px', height: this.options.initialHeight+'px', marginLeft: '-'+(this.options.initialWidth/2)+'px', display: 'none'}).injectInside(document.body);

    this.bottomContainer = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottomContainer').setStyle('display', 'none').injectInside(document.body);
    this.bottom = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottom').injectInside(this.bottomContainer);
    new Element('a').setProperties({id: 'lbCloseLink', href: '#'}).injectInside(this.bottom).onclick = this.overlay.onclick = this.close.bind(this);
    this.caption = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCaption').injectInside(this.bottom);
    this.number = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbNumber').injectInside(this.bottom);
    new Element('div').setStyle('clear', 'both').injectInside(this.bottom);

    var nextEffect = this.nextEffect.bind(this);
    this.fx = {
        overlay: this.overlay.effect('opacity', {duration: 500}).hide(),
        center: this.center.effects({duration: 500, transition: Fx.Transitions.sineInOut, onComplete: nextEffect}),
        bottom: this.bottom.effect('margin-top', {duration: 400})
    };

},

click: function(link) {

        return this.open (link.href, link.title, link.rel);

},
open: function(sLinkHref, sLinkTitle, sLinkRel) {
    this.href = sLinkHref;
    this.title = sLinkTitle;
    this.rel = sLinkRel;
    this.position();
    this.setup();
    this.video(this.href);
    this.top = Window.getScrollTop() + (Window.getHeight() / 15);
    this.center.setStyles({top: this.top+'px', display: ''});
    this.fx.overlay.start(0.8);
    this.step = 1;
    this.center.setStyle('background','#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat center');
    this.caption.innerHTML = this.title;
    this.fx.center.start({'height': [this.options.contentsHeight]});
},

setup: function(){
    var aDim = this.rel.match(/[0-9]+/g);
    this.options.contentsWidth = (aDim && (aDim[0] > 0)) ? aDim[0] : this.options.defaultWidth;
    this.options.contentsHeight = (aDim && (aDim[1] > 0)) ? aDim[1] : this.options.defaultHeight;

},

position: function(){
this.overlay.setStyles({'top': window.getScrollTop()+'px', 'height': window.getHeight()+'px'});
},

video: function(sLinkHref){
    if (sLinkHref.match(/youtube\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/metacafe\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('/');
        this.videoID = videoId[4];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/"+this.videoID+"/.swf", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/google\.com\/videoplay/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId="+this.videoID+"&hl=en", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/ifilm\.com\/video/i)) {
      this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('video/');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.ifilm.com/efp", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
        this.so.addVariable("flvbaseclip", this.videoID+"&");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.mov/i)) {
      this.flash = false;
        if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length) {
      this.other ='<object id="qtboxMovie" type="video/quicktime" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" data="'+sLinkHref+'" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  } else {
    this.other = '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" id="qtboxMovie"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  }
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.wmv/i) || sLinkHref.match(/\.asx/i)) {
    this.flash = false;
     this.other = '<object NAME="Player" WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" type="application/x-oleobject" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"><param NAME="URL" VALUE="'+sLinkHref+'"><param><param NAME="AUTOSTART" VALUE="false"></param><param name="showControls" value="true"></param><embed WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" SRC="'+sLinkHref+'" TYPE="application/x-oleobject" AUTOSTART="false"></embed></object>'
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.flv/i)) {
     this.flash = true;
     this.so = new SWFObject(this.options.flvplayer+"?file="+sLinkHref, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
    }
    else {
      this.flash = true;
        this.videoID = sLinkHref;
        this.so = new SWFObject(this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
    }
},

nextEffect: function(){
    switch (this.step++){
    case 1:
        this.fx.center.start({'width': [this.options.contentsWidth], 'marginLeft': [this.options.contentsWidth/-2]});
        break;
        this.step++;
    case 2:
        this.center.setStyle('background','#fff');
        this.flash ? this.so.write(this.center) : this.center.setHTML(this.other) ;
        this.bottomContainer.setStyles({top: (this.top + this.center.clientHeight)+'px', height: '0px', marginLeft: this.center.style.marginLeft, width: this.options.contentsWidth+'px',display: ''});
        if (this.options.animateCaption){
            this.fx.bottom.set(-this.bottom.offsetHeight);
            this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
            this.fx.bottom.start(0);
            break;
        }
        this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
        this.step++;
    }
},

close: function(){
    this.fx.overlay.start(0);
    this.center.style.display = this.bottomContainer.style.display = 'none';
    this.center.innerHTML = '';
    return false;
}

};
window.addEvent('domready', Videobox.init.bind(Videobox));
```

Comment: what does your lightbox implementation look like? provide code please

Comment: Is there something I could add to the audio player's script that would signal a stop when the <a> is clicked? Maybe using a certain class?

Comment: yes, let me whip something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$('a[rel=vidbox]').click(function () {

    if ($("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("playing") === true) {
        $("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("pause");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HM8m7/).

Bit of advise; if you are using mootools to solely use the Videobox then you should think about switching to a jQuery lightbox. Videobox seems to be very limited (looking at it's source) in terms of customization and callback support. Plugins such as Fancybox and Colorbox (jQuery) offers much more flexibility.

Comment: I tried Fancybox and Colorbox, but I never could get either of them to work correctly. Most recently, everytime I embedded a video with Fancybox, it filled the entire screen.

Comment: probably because of an implementation error. If you are able to post a jsfiddle with your fancybox implementation, I could help.

Comment: Also, I couldn't get the solution above to work in context. It simply continues to play.

Comment: Probably a conflict with Videobox. If you can, post a jsfiddle of your code for me to work on.

Comment: Finally fixed it, guys! Thanks a million!