# Stopping an audio track on a mouse click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, lightbox

I'm learning some beginners front end development. I've created a very simple website which utilizes the Lightbox kit.  I have worked out how to start an audio track when someone clicks a thumbnail but need some pointers as to how to stop it, or for a more robust solution, play the appropriate track if someone clicks the 'next' arrow. Here is my code so far:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">
    <script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>verenti ltd</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F7FBED  ">

<div class="gallery">
    <a href="images/drake_big.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="nick drake"
       onclick=PlaySound("music/drake.mp3")><img src="images/drake_small.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/prine_big.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="john prine"
       onclick=PlaySound("music/prine.mp3")> <img src="images/prine_small.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/westerberg_big.jpeg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="paul westerberg"
       onclick=PlaySound("music/westerberg.mp3")> <img src="images/westerberg_small.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/townes_big.png" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="townes van zandt"
       onclick=PlaySound("music/townes.mp3")> <img src="images/townes_small.jpg"></a>
    <script>
        function PlaySound(path) {
            //this function will work like a toggler for sound track playing
            var sound = document.getElementById(path);
            if(sound && sound.currentTime > 0){ //check whether it is already playing
                sound.pause();// stop the sound
                sound.currentTime = 0 //
            }else if(sound){
                //this block to play paused sound track
                sound.play();
            }else{
                //this block to play new sound track
                sound= document.createElement('audio');
                sound.setAttribute('src', path);
                sound.setAttribute('id', path);
                sound.play();
            }
        }

    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I could be making better use of the  tag?

Comment: i think i found a question that answers mine but does it with a lot more code. I wonder if I can use something simpler for now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307663/jquery-audio-stop-once-link-is-clicked

Comment: Create a complete example (without missing elements) so we will be able to help.

Comment: @dekel fair comment - complete page now included, along with the suggested new script as well as the url where I am hosting.

Comment: Your "completed page" is not working, because you link to elements that does not exists here on stackoverflow (the images, the mp3 files, the js). With regards to the page in your hosting - it doesn't help, because next week it might change (or become unavailable), so this the answer you will get will not help anyone at that stage. Take the time to create a working example. You can use jsfiddle/codepen/jsbin for that.

Comment: @Dekel I was looking for a quick pointer, that's all.  You want me to include all 3k lines of lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js??  The images are in 2 types - thumbnail and large - that's patently obvious from the url. the mp3 files number 4 and, guess what, live under /music under root.  Seriously, I will work through it myself.

Comment: 1. You can include the js file from a cdn. 2. you can create an example without the actual big/small images, but a text. If you want a hint - you should use the `pause` function on the media element.

Comment: @Dekel 1.don't assume others will understand acronyms 2.thanks, the answer below told me that.

Comment: sorry about that. Not sure what acronym you refer to. Are you talking about cdn? js? (sorry, those are pretty common for web developers).

Comment: @Dekel -'cdn' I'm not a Web Developer! Goodbye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution will be:

```
    <script>
    function PlaySound(path) {
            //this function will work like a toggler for sound track playing
            var sound = document.getElementById(path);
            if(sound && sound.currentTime > 0){ //check whether it is already playing
               sound.pause();// stop the sound
               sound.currentTime = 0 //
            }else if(sound){
                 //this block to play paused sound track

               sound.play();
            }else{
                 //this block to play new sound track

                  sound= document.createElement('audio');
                  sound.setAttribute('src', path);
                  sound.setAttribute('id', path);
                  sound.play();
            }


    }

</script>
```

Comment: thank you. This doesn't seem to work - I think would need some kind of event listener for the mouse clicks on the lightboxes? To be fair, I didn't include a full example but have now updated.

Comment: does playSound function invoke on lightbox click? or is it throwing error while calling ? can you just tell what happens on clicking it. Thanks.
also if possible try dummy div and image inside it and have onclick on div and check whether the function is working.

Comment: yes it is invoked on lightbox click, but it is not stopped or paused when closing the lightbox using the 'x' control.

Comment: @Steerpike please have a look at this code [code for sound function check](http://playcode.io/156986?tabs=console&index.html&output) and try it on w3 in this link [paste code here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_create) to here the audio